# Easy brain stumper, a better algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

This was at a community college.  I failed it, but want to know the answer.

The problem is this: you have an 2D array of structs that represents an image.  Each struct has a red, green, blue, and alpha value.  There can be more info, but not required to solve the problem.

Say the image is 4000x4000 or 16 Million elements.  Every element needs to be updated/checked on every turn.

For each element you need to:

- Set the red byte to 50 if < 50 or set to 205 > 205
- Set the green byte to a random value between 0 and 255 using rand()
- Modify blue in an "interesting" way.

"You can't brute force this, think in a smarter way; you need a better algorithm"

I basically did a loop.  I was the fastest but he said it was "about finding a better algorithm, not using using cute compiler and pointer tricks".

Also needs to be in pure C.  No OpenMP/Threads or OpenGL shading, OpenCL, etc... just ANSI C with standard libraries (even GNU/POSIX libraries were forbidden).

I asked about bitwise operations and he said that "those are very expensive in C [??] and it's about writing a fast and solid algorithm, not these cute tricks you keep coming up with".

So any hints?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. Loop over all pixels and apply the algorithm. Set red to appropriate value, set green to random, and do-whatever to blue. If you have 16 million (or any number to be honest) unrelated values, you can't really do much better than visit every one of them.

Comment: I second your [??]. Bitwise operations are very cheap.

Comment: Is the purpose of this class to teach you something, or just to entertain the teacher? Why didn't he tell you his answer at the end?

Comment: Can you post/link to the full problem statement? What you've described here is something that requires touching every element. All you can do to improve that sort of thing is "tricks". So I suspect that problem lets you take a completely different direction, without touching all elements.

Comment: @Steve: It was probably neither, it was probably created to make the student feel inferior.

Comment: Every value has to be visited. You could maybe do all 4 of rgba at once, but other than that there's no better algorithm short of special hardware. He might have been thinking of some system call and was unaware it's the same algorithm but hidden from view. (His remarks on bitwise operators show he doesn't know much about computers...)

Comment: Please pass on a -1 to the teacher.

Comment: Bitwise operations are not "expensive" in C, in most cases they are faster. Usually compiler makes the decision when to use bitwise operations even if you didnt write them into your code.

Comment: Why not post your answer, so we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your teacher sounds like a pr*ck

Comment: Tell you teacher to come over here and talk to us. **;D**

Comment: What do you mean by "red bit", "green bit"? The struct contains a ushort for each r,g,b,a fields, right?  Do you mean "set the Red value to 50 if it's less than 50"? How do you set a red bit to 50?

Comment: Assuming that you're not entirely misrepresenting what the instructor said, drop the class: the instructor is an idiot.

Comment: At first this sounded like a matrix exponentiation problem, but then I was disappointed because doing this process once is just as good as doing it a billion times. @Stealth Rabbi: I think that he meant byte not bit.

Comment: @Stealth, @Justin - "bit" is in English a synonym for "part" or "piece", as well as being a jargon abbreviation of binary digit. Not a great choice of words given the context, but it's still valid.

Comment: My thought on the question - sometimes the point of an assignment may be that you're supposed to say "that's not possible" and explain why.

Comment: I don't understand why this terrible question has received so many upvotes!  As stated, there is no structure to the problem that would enable a faster "algorithm".  I feel sorry for the student, but -1 for a bad question anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1

The single most important point in updating a big array is exploiting the [memory hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy) by using locality. This hides memory latency and thus accelerates you algorithm.

First, you want to process the colors of each pixel together as they lie in the same struct. The processing of a pixel fits entirely in the register set of modern CPUs. Depending on the actual storage some bit/byte/word tweaking is possible here but it sounds like your instructor doesn't place emphasis on this point.

Second, you want to update the pixels in the order they are stored in memory. This means looping over the inner array dimension in the inner loop. This enables the compiler and the CPU to access the pixels efficiently in big chunks (keywords cache-lines and prefetching).

### Solution 2

A completely different approach is adding a layer of indirection.

Instead of accessing the image array directly, route all accesses through accessor functions. Now you can write accessor functions that implement the required changes to the image without needing to access the array or even loop over all pixels at all!

This is like the Decorator pattern in an object-oriented language.

Comment: With a not very strict interpretation of "every element needs to be updated" ;-)

Comment: @Howard Some call it cheating, I call it thinking out of the box :)

Comment: On the "process the colors of each pixel together", it's worth mentioning memory bandwidth - multiple passes would multiply the amount of stuff needing to pass through the data bus.

Comment: On the nesting of the loops, good point, but I had interpreted the questions solution as referring to *a* (single) loop - as in "basically I did a loop" - over the full 16 million elements, translating the two dimensions into one. It's basically equivalent, but the optimisation is less fragile. Reverse the sense of the two dimensions somehow and it's still optimised. Of course some compilers will probably handle this anyway, spotting that the nesting order doesn't change the final result, making the source code nesting order irrelevant.

Comment: Solution 2 is, as you say, a design pattern - not an algorithm. The indirection will not improve performance, and may (if you're unlucky) add overheads. For example, if the accessor functions aren't inlined by the compiler, a lot of optimisations that would have happened for a simple loop will not be applicable. So - not a more efficient algorithm, but maybe a more flexible design with (probably) no significant cost.

Comment: @Steve314 It depends on the whole setting. If you apply hundreds of the simple modifications in a row without accessing the intermediate results, it should pay to calculate a single resulting modification first and then make the final access to all pixels.

Comment: @Steve314 Basically I offered Solution 2 for guys who are dissatisfied with the Performance of standard processing like Solution 1. Solution 2 offers a way to be faster using only ISO C and its libraries. However, there is no free lunch. Solution 2 can only be faster in specialized scenarios like the one I detailed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, let's all figure out how to write an alogirithm to "Modify blue in an 'interesting' way.", as long as it's "fast and solid". Glad community colleges are teaching so strong. I've never heard that bitwise operations are expensive. Expensive compared to what? When you say that you were "the fastest", do you mean that you were the first to come up with an answer, or that your answer was the most efficient implementation? If you're forced to store the data as a 2D array of structs (as opposed to a tree), I'm not sure what else you can expect to do. So you know that you failed it, but were not told the correct answer? Now that's what I call edjumacation!

Comment: by the blue he meant change it to whatever you want.  Set them all the 65 or whatever.  It doesn't matter what happens to blue as long as you did "something" with it. The point of the exercise was to find a good way to quickly manipulation all the elements in the array, the specifics on the manipulation weren't important.  ---  By "fastest" he meant by run/execution time.

Comment: Don't know if this would be allowed; but say you could change the 2d array into a tree; how would you do it then?

Comment: @user697111 - How "interesting" is "set them all to 65"?

Answer (score 5):

**The `rand()` calls will most likely dominate the runtime of the program**, so there is no point in trying to be smart with a smart loop structure or fancy bitwise operations.

So it is likely that the most effective optimization would actualy be spliting each value from rand into bytes (depends on rand implementation), to do less calls.

---

As for what the teacher actually wanted, here is a wild guess:

1. Use rand to set the green byte
2. Use some fancy method to set the red byte
3. Include the blue byte somewhere in your fancy method, so it gets a new value as a convenient side effect
4. End up with a cryptic and pointless one-liner (because he thinks the less lines a program has the faster is must run)

Comment: since the rand() calls dominate the runtime, wouldn't the biggest optimization be use one rand() call for every 4 pixels?

Comment: @Jimmy: Sily me! For some reason I though rand only returned in [0,256)...

Comment: `rand()` returns values from zero up to `RAND_MAX`, which is a platform-dependent value only guaranteed to be at least 32767. So you're only guaranteed to get 15 bits of randomness per call. Splitting one return value into four might therefore give bad results, depending on your platform.

Comment: Man, gotta love the C nerds :)

Comment: On the RAND_MAX thing - this isn't just a theoretical limitation. Microsoft Visual C++ (the 2008 version, IIRC - certainly the 2003 version) only gives 15 bits for each rand() call. You could do some bit-shifting stuff to almost halve your number of rand calls anyway, but using a different random number generator would be better. Maybe in more ways than just speed, since standard library rand() implementations often aren't very high quality.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an interview question. It's silly! If you have to visit each pixel, then you have to use loops! After all, this is their purpose. The best thing you can do is doing a single loop instead of two and edit more pixels on every iteration

Comment: How is a single loop algorithmically better than two loops, when you are visiting every pixel?

Comment: @crypto: algorithmically there's no difference, but it might be faster

Comment: Even better would be to do more operations per iteration. Like manipulating eight pixels on every iteration instead of just one pixel.

Answer (score 2):

ok - i see something interesting...

'on every turn'

so maybe there is some optimization to not perform red checking after the first iteration since those values will be static

Comment: That's what I did, after first run I set a isRedSet=1 and if set, just ignored red checks I also defined blue as red value (he accepted that); so after first run the only thing was green=rand().  That wasn't accepted though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can figure this is that "Say the image is 4000x4000 or 16 Million elements. Every element **needs** to be updated/checked on every turn." actually means "Say the image is 4000x4000 or 16 Million elements. Every element **would need** to be updated/checked on every turn."

Then, it says "Also needs to be in pure C. No OpenMP/Threads or OpenGL shading, OpenCL, etc..." Why mention "OpenGL shading" for such a basic question?

I think (I'm only guessing) the actual question had more detail and was pushing the student towards clipping the image processing in some way (ie. some part of the image is covered or off screen, so you can skip those bits).

It's just a guess. As my kid brother would say "It don't make sense otherwise!!!"

Comment: agreed - somehting is lost in translation

Comment: I asked him if I could use threads.  It's a good problem for parallelism since there is no dependencies between elements.  You could do say 8 million elements per thread (on dual core) and get it done "twice" as fast.  He said that wasn't the point of it and not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the instructor was looking for some performance gained by processing the colors in separate loops:

```
for each pixel
    red pixel = (red pixel < 50) ? 50 : ((red pixel > 250) ? 250 : red pixel);
end-for

for each pixel
    green pixel = 256 * rand()
end-for

for each pixel
    blue pixel = (green pixel * 1024) % 256;
end-for
```

This **may** have some better performance, but only profiling will tell.

### Edit 1:

An advantage to this method is that each color can be processed by an independent thread or core.

Comment: He wasn't allowed to use threads, and even if he was, splitting the computation up this way would only serve to maximize the amount of false sharing occuring, making performance terrible.